# Repair MRAM that's been exposed to a magnetic field

Tags: pcb, damage, non-volatile-memory, mram

Is there any way to repair MRAM that has been exposed to a magnetic field?
I've got a bit stuck (3rd bit) on my MRAM. Probably due to exposure to a magnetic field.
Is there any way to fix this short of completely desoldering the MRAM and replacing it?

Comment: I guess you could try degaussing it, but that could damage something else on the PCB.

Comment: At the moment it is broken regardless. I'll have a go at it. (It's a commercial thing and they casted the PCB in epoxy......)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to remove the magnetization by degaussing. Typically, the magnetic tunneling junction (MTJ) in an MRAM cell has one ferromagnetic layer whose magnetization can be changed by applying a current and one ferromagnetic layer that is **pinned**, meaning that its magnetization does not change.

I suppose that if you exposed the MRAM to a very high magnetic field you could change the magnetization of the pinned layer so that the MTJ didn't work properly. If that's the case then you might be able to fix it by applying the desired magnetic field to the pinned layer, but that sounds risky to me and you would need to consult the MRAM manufacturer.

Comment: at most it got exposed to a clip magnet to keep something shut.In order to do what you are suggesting I would need a homogeneous magnetic field applied to the MRAM but that is quite difficult to do. But I think that even if it is degaussed this method should still work to fix the issue. https://www.swtest.org/swtw_library/2004proc/PDF/S01_01_Robertazzi.pdf Here they do a degaussing sequence on MRAM. It seems to work

Comment: Magnetization in a homogeneous magnetic field works to set everything to 0 but it is stuck on 0 now. Seems it can't be fixed